# Deploying Svelte App to Heroku / Dokku fails because modules cannot be found

Tags: node.js, heroku, svelte, rollupjs, dokku

I am having problems deploying my svelte web3 App to my VPS running Dokku.
The structure of the folder is as follows:

```
root
|-->svelte 
|--> ...
```

I found some solutions to work with the two folders needing npm install around here. So I put:
`"heroku-postbuild": "cd ./svelte && npm install && npm run build"` and `"cacheDirectories": ["./node_modules", "./svelte/node_modules"]` in the root package.json.
But when the process comes to this point it fails with the following error:

```
remote: [!] Error: Cannot find module '@rollup/plugin-node-resolve'
remote: Require stack:
remote: - /tmp/build/svelte/rollup.config.js
remote: - /tmp/build/svelte/node_modules/rollup/dist/shared/loadConfigFile.js
remote: - /tmp/build/svelte/node_modules/rollup/dist/bin/rollup
```

I've tried changing the import to include the full paths etc. but nothing has worked so far. I have also changed the order of the imports, but the process fails with the first import in the rollup.config.
Any ideas?

package.json root:

```
 "scripts": {
    "heroku-postbuild": "cd ./svelte && npm install && npm run build"
    
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@openzeppelin/contracts": "^4.6.0",
    "@truffle/hdwallet-provider": "^2.0.8",
    "babel-polyfill": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-register": "^6.26.0",
    "dotenv": "^16.0.0",
    "web3": "^1.7.3"
  },
  "cacheDirectories": ["./node_modules", "./svelte/node_modules"],
  "engines": {
    "node": "16.14",
    "npm": "8.7.x"
  }
}
```

package.json svelte (added all the dev dependencies again just in case)

```
{
  "name": "app",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "build": "rollup -c",
    "dev": "rollup -c -w",
    "start": "sirv public --no-clear"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@rollup/plugin-commonjs": "^17.0.0",
    "@rollup/plugin-node-resolve": "^11.0.0",
    "rollup": "^2.3.4",
    "rollup-plugin-css-only": "^3.1.0",
    "rollup-plugin-livereload": "^2.0.0",
    "rollup-plugin-svelte": "^7.0.0",
    "rollup-plugin-terser": "^7.0.0",
    "svelte": "^3.0.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "rollup-plugin-terser": "^7.0.0",
    "svelte": "^3.0.0",
    "@rollup/plugin-commonjs": "^17.0.0",
    "@rollup/plugin-node-resolve": "^11.0.0",
    "rollup-plugin-css-only": "^3.1.0",
    "rollup": "^2.3.4",
    "rollup-plugin-svelte": "^7.0.0",
    "@rollup/plugin-json": "^4.1.0",
    "apexcharts": "^3.35.0",
    "bootstrap": "^5.1.3",
    "moment": "^2.29.2",
    "rollup-plugin-copy": "^3.4.0",
    "sirv-cli": "^2.0.0",
    "svelte-web3": "^3.4.0"
  }
}
```

rollup.config.js

````
import resolve from '@rollup/plugin-node-resolve';
import { nodeResolve } from '@rollup/plugin-node-resolve';
import svelte from 'node_modules/rollup-plugin-svelte';
import commonjs from 'node_modules/@rollup/plugin-commonjs';
import livereload from 'node_modules/rollup-plugin-livereload';
import { terser } from 'node_modules/rollup-plugin-terser';
import css from 'node_modules/rollup-plugin-css-only';
import json from 'node_modules/@rollup/plugin-json';
import copy from 'node_modules/rollup-plugin-copy'

const production = !process.env.ROLLUP_WATCH;

function serve() {
    let server;

    function toExit() {
        if (server) server.kill(0);
    }

    return {
        writeBundle() {
            if (server) return;
            server = require('child_process').spawn('npm', ['run', 'start', '--', '--dev'], {
                stdio: ['ignore', 'inherit', 'inherit'],
                shell: true
            });

            process.on('SIGTERM', toExit);
            process.on('exit', toExit);
        }
    };
}

export default {
    input: 'src/main.js',
    output: {
        sourcemap: true,
        format: 'iife',
        name: 'app',
        file: 'public/build/bundle.js'
    },
    plugins: [
        svelte({
            compilerOptions: {
                // enable run-time checks when not in production
                dev: !production
            }
        }),
        // we'll extract any component CSS out into
        // a separate file - better for performance
        css({ output: 'bundle.css' }),

        // If you have external dependencies installed from
        // npm, you'll most likely need these plugins. In
        // some cases you'll need additional configuration -
        // consult the documentation for details:
        // https://github.com/rollup/plugins/tree/master/packages/commonjs
        resolve({
            browser: true,
            dedupe: ['svelte']
        }),
        commonjs(),
        json(),
        nodeResolve(),
        copy({
            targets: [{ 
                src: './node_modules/bootstrap/dist/**/*', 
                dest: 'public/vendor/bootstrap' 
            }]
        }),

        // In dev mode, call `npm run start` once
        // the bundle has been generated
        !production && serve(),

        // Watch the `public` directory and refresh the
        // browser on changes when not in production
        !production && livereload('public'),

        // If we're building for production (npm run build
        // instead of npm run dev), minify
        production && terser()
    ],
    watch: {
        clearScreen: false
    }
};

```
````

Comment: Could you post your rollup config & package.json?

Comment: Sure I added the question.

Comment: Is there a reason why you have the svelte code in a separate directory?

Comment: No, no real reason I just initialised the svelte standard app in the subfolder, because I used to have a react app in the root.

Comment: I would suggest you start from scratch and put everything in one directory. The issue is caused by the multiple directories. Also the dependencies need to be placed in the right section, read up a bit on the difference between devDependencies and dependencies.

Comment: Thanks for your help so far! I moved it all in one folder but I am still getting the same error. 
`code`
remote: [!] Error: Cannot find module '@rollup/plugin-json'
remote: Require stack:
remote: - /tmp/build/rollup.config.js
remote: - /tmp/build/node_modules/rollup/dist/shared/loadConfigFile.js
remote: - /tmp/build/node_modules/rollup/dist/bin/rollup
remote: Error: Cannot find module '@rollup/plugin-json'
remote: Require stack:
remote: - /tmp/build/rollup.config.js
remote: - /tmp/build/node_modules/rollup/dist/shared/loadConfigFile.js
...
`code`